# iOS17.xのUnitTestでサブスクリプションの課金復元テスト時に「Code=-1005 "ネットワーク接続が切れました。」というエラーになる

Tags: ios, xcode

【状況】
iOS17.xでサブスクリプション(課金)のリストア処理を行う部分をUnitTestで「ネットワーク接続が切れました」というエラーになります。iOS16.x、iOS15.xでは同じ症状にはなりません。

【環境】
・Xcode15.1
・iOS Simulator iPhone 15 Pro(iOS17.2)
・Swift 5.8
・SwiftyStoreKit ver.0.16.1
https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit

```
RestoreResults(restoredPurchases: [], restoreFailedPurchases: [(__C_Synthesized.related decl 'e' for SKErrorCode(_nsError: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "ネットワーク接続が切れました。...
```

【質問】
・同じ症状に遭遇した方がいらっしゃる場合、対処法など知見をいただきたい。
・iOS 17.xでのサブスクリプションのリストア処理について何か公式で変更はあったか？など何か情報があれば

【参考】
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737665